# How search the option from select dropdown which search from first letter using antd?

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown, antd

(eg) options in the list (USD, AUD, EUR)
If I search 'U' it should display 'USD' only

```
<Select
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={onChange}
    onFocus={onFocus}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    onSearch={onSearch}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
  >
```

It getting all the list value which all have 'U'

How can set the filterOption in select

Thanks in advance <3

Link to refer
[CodeSandBox Select](https://codesandbox.io/s/h7snq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking where `indexOf >= 0`, use `===` instead, to force it to only check if it's matched at the start of the string:

```
filterOption={(input, option) =>
  option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) === 0
}
```

Updated codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-meninsky-r3s54). You'll see it matches Lucy only on L, and not on U.

Alternatively, you can use [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```
filterOption={(input, option) =>
  option.props.children.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase())
}
```